# Principal component analysis for detecting disease rate

Tags: r, pca

I have a disease dataset, and I need to do `PCA` for this dataset.
`disease_rate` is the dependent variable and the rest are independent.

```
data <- read.csv("H:/uni/MS_DS/disease.csv")
data

> data
         radius      texture perimeter   area smoothness desease_rate
1  -0.018743998  0.002521470 -0.005025 0.0710 0.00000000         0.07
2  -0.027940652  0.003164681 -0.004625 0.0706 0.06476967         0.02
3   0.002615946  0.001328688 -0.005525 0.0726 0.06268457         0.07
4   0.041963329  0.002769471 -0.004325 0.0699 0.06013138         0.06
5   0.030261380  0.005725780 -0.003525 0.0695 0.05942403         0.04
6  -0.030559594  0.001576348 -0.002525 0.0695 0.06110087         0.05
7   0.002698690 -0.003028856 -0.006025 0.0706 0.06207810         0.07
8  -0.044996901  0.000617110 -0.009525 0.0691 0.05940039         0.05
9   0.022993350 -0.000637109 -0.015425 0.0695 0.05870643         0.03
10  0.001398530 -0.000470057 -0.017125 0.0705 0.05540871         0.01
11  0.026827990  0.000509490 -0.014025 0.0681 0.05588225         0.06
12 -0.076220726  0.001018820 -0.010225 0.0631 0.05515852         0.01
13 -0.021917789  0.000822517 -0.003925 0.0576 0.05584590         0.03
14  0.012491060 -0.007363090  0.005175 0.0569 0.05120000         0.03
15  0.038281834 -0.008005798  0.014975 0.0576 0.04940000         0.06
16 -0.033198384  0.000350052  0.022875 0.0564 0.04930000         0.01
17 -0.002358179  0.003846831  0.022675 0.0572 0.05050000         0.07
18  0.020808766  0.000536629  0.024575 0.0656 0.04820000         0.04
19  0.091888897 -0.002393641  0.009775 0.0761 0.04740000         0.07
20 -0.036293550 -0.002889337  0.001775 0.0828 0.04770000         0.01
```

Do the PCA method to find the best combinations of the independent variable.

I'm not sure how to read the output with the below results.

How can I determine the best combination of x for y?

```
> prcomp(df1[1:5])
Standard deviations (1, .., p=5):
[1] 0.037965339 0.014474647 0.012090835 0.005871033 0.003245097

Rotation (n x k) = (5 x 5):
                    PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4          PC5
radius      0.997199119  0.03379814 -0.04756462  0.04123499  0.022110746
texture    -0.020381835  0.02458424 -0.03284838 -0.09819650  0.994111979
perimeter   0.068696517 -0.60330896  0.71627488 -0.34382115  0.006034021
area        0.020363690  0.14813495 -0.32213733 -0.92882163 -0.105637459
smoothness  0.006678794  0.78251367  0.61630872 -0.08794608 -0.007537012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prcomp(data[1:5])
```

This will give you the the values for the PCA. You can look at the relation between the original values and the PCs under the "rotation" tag.

The classical PCA plot can be seen using:

```
biplot(prcomp(data[1:5]))
```

Comment: i got some output, but need an explanation to detemine the best combination of x variables. please check the edited question for result.

Comment: The best way is to look in the biplot. Look for large arrows, and for those who are close to perpendicular to each other. By trying to picture the graph from your rotation table it seems radius is unique and important (it dominates PC1 which is by definition the axis that explain most variance). Permiter and smoothness come second (most influent in PC2) but they have a strong inverse relation, with smoothness performing better=. PC3 is shared by perimiter and smoothness, which overall gives the impression radius and smoothness are the best to use

Answer (score 1):

PCA is not designed to do what you want.  PCA is a data reduction method. A method that is somewhat similar to PCA but *does* look at the dependent variable is partial least squares.

However, I am a bit concerned about two things: First, do you actually have only 20 cases, or is this a subset of your data?  Second, from the names of the variables, it seems like some will be inherently related; in particular, radius, perimeter and area all sound like measures of size.  If this is so, then you may be able to reduce the number of variables via substantive knowledge rather than statistical methods.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, the usual thing is to upvote it and accept it.